# Undefined symbol when importing Sequential

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I get error once I want to ‍import `Sequential` from `keras.models`; how to deal with it?

```
from keras.models import Sequential

-----
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from keras.models import Sequential
      2 from keras.layers import Dense
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/__init__.py:24, in <module>
     21 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     22 from keras import distribute
---> 24 from keras import models
     26 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     27 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/models/__init__.py:18, in <module>
     15 """Keras models API."""
     16 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 18 from keras.engine.functional import Functional
     19 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     20 from keras.engine.training import Model
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:24, in <module>
     22 import warnings
     23 from keras import backend
---> 24 from keras.dtensor import layout_map as layout_map_lib
     25 from keras.engine import base_layer
     26 from keras.engine import base_layer_utils
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/dtensor/__init__.py:22, in <module>
     20 # Conditional import the dtensor API, since it is currently broken in OSS.
     21 if _DTENSOR_API_ENABLED:
---> 22   from tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental import dtensor as dtensor_api  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
     23 else:
     24   # Leave it with a placeholder, so that the import line from other python file
     25   # will not break.
     26   dtensor_api = None
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v2/experimental/dtensor/__init__.py:8, in <module>
      3 """Public API for tf.experimental.dtensor namespace.
      4 """
      6 import sys as _sys
----> 8 from tensorflow.dtensor.python.api import call_with_layout
      9 from tensorflow.dtensor.python.api import check_layout
     10 from tensorflow.dtensor.python.api import client_id
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/dtensor/python/__init__.py:19, in <module>
     15 """DTensor Python API."""
     17 from tensorflow.dtensor.python import gen_dtensor_ops as ops
---> 19 from tensorflow.dtensor.python.api import call_with_layout
     20 from tensorflow.dtensor.python.api import check_layout
     21 from tensorflow.dtensor.python.api import client_id
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/dtensor/python/api.py:22, in <module>
     19 import threading
     20 from typing import Any, Callable, List, Optional, Sequence, Union
---> 22 from tensorflow.dtensor.python import dtensor_device
     23 from tensorflow.dtensor.python import gen_dtensor_ops
     24 from tensorflow.dtensor.python import layout as layout_lib
 
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/dtensor/python/dtensor_device.py:29, in <module>
     27 from tensorflow.dtensor.python import gen_dtensor_ops
     28 from tensorflow.dtensor.python import layout as layout_lib
---> 29 from tensorflow.python import _pywrap_dtensor_device
     30 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     31 from tensorflow.python.eager import core

ImportError: /home/saifullah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_dtensor_device.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow7dtensor4PackEP11TFE_ContextiPP16TFE_TensorHandleRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPvP9TF_Status, version tensorflow
```

Comment: Try to update Keras and TensorFlow `pip install -U keras` and `pip install -U tensorflow`. Then try to import from tensorflow like `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`.

Comment: Hey @Kaveh i have gone through your instruction the requirements already satisfied and still getting same error man, any other solution plz

Comment: Could you please try again by upgrading pip using `pip install --upgrade pip`? Also let us know which OS you are using and what are all steps you followed to install `TensorFlow` in your system if the issue still persists.